# Worklight - How to pass parameters in an adapter procedure invocation in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parameters, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I've been searching and haven't found any answers. I would like to invoke an adapter procedure from my native iOS code. Based on research, this is the code to do that...

```
WLProcedureInvocationData *myInvocationData = [[WLProcedureInvocationData 
alloc] initWithAdapterName:@"RSSReader" procedureName:@"getStoriesFiltered"];
MyInvokeListener *invokeListener = [[MyInvokeListener alloc] initWithController: self];
[[WLClient sharedInstance] invokeProcedure:myInvocationData withDelegate:invokeListener];
```

But, my procedure requires parameters. How can I pass the parameters?

Comment: Check this out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O-4YJVaBBUc#t=889. The sample is with Swift but you get the idea. Basically the invocationData has a property parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not find good documentation for this particular requirement as well.
I've asked to enhance the docs. Thanks.

You can see the 'implementation' for the below in WLProcedureInvocationData.h.

Here's how to do it in the application.
See the second line:

```
WLProcedureInvocationData *myInvocationData = [[WLProcedureInvocationData alloc] initWithAdapterName:@"RSSReader" procedureName:@"getStoriesFiltered"];

myInvocationData.parameters = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Africa", nil];
```